# Is it possible to format a graphql fetch result into a readable list?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I'm fetching a graphql query using jsfiddle to return information about a collection of tokens, along with their names, symbols, ids etc

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/ydjtvha9/37/)

```
 var WalletAddress = "0x980c55E501D2fAd60b5702e2FD88232137e12145"
 var query = `
  query (
    $WalletAddress: String!
) {
  ethereum(network: bsc) {
    address(address: {is: $WalletAddress}) {
      address
      balances {
        currency {
          address
          decimals
          name
          symbol
        }
       # value
      }
    }
  }
}


      `
 
 
 
 fetch('https://graphql.bitquery.io/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY': 'BQY1NlSY2ovBeovybKJ07zdWmtDC5cny'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query,
    variables: { WalletAddress },
  }),
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  
  .then((result) =>alert(JSON.stringify(result)))
```

I need to format this response into a list of the "address" fields,  so something like:

0x2a9718deff471f3bb91fa0eceab14154f150a385,
0xad90c05bc51672eedfee36e58b3ff1a78bbc146d,
0x33a3d962955a3862c8093d1273344719f03ca17c

Is this something that can be configured within the graphql query itself or do we need do this after the query has run?

Any advice on how we can fetch only the Address fields would be much appreciated

Comment: after fetch, of course ... fetch only required fields (address)

Comment: try .then((res) => {
        const {var1, var2}=res.json();
    }